# Term vectors for nested objects not working

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm trying to retrieve term vectors for a document with `nested` field. Here's my mapping:

```
PUT /mcve/ex/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "parent": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "value": {"type": "string", "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets", "store": true, "analyzer": "polish"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I'm inserting a document:

```
PUT /mcve/ex/ample
{
  "parent": {
    "value": "ala ma kota"
  }
}
```

And asking for term vectors:

```
GET /mcve/ex/ample/_termvectors
{
  "fields": ["parent.value"]
}
```

The response contains empty object in the `term_vectors` field. I thought that maybe term vectors don't work within `nested` objects and indeed, it works without `"type": "nested"`.

There's a weird thing, though: **if I don't store the term vector, the query above works perfectly**. This mapping works just fine:

```
PUT /mcve/ex/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "parent": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "value": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "polish"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently ES *can* calculate term vectors for `nested` objects, but they break when I store them. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

This is documented behavior.  See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21625 for more details.

Comment: Well, you're right - it's documented _now_, but it wasn't when I asked this question. They documented it two years later. [GitHub issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21625).

Comment: Understood, and hope my reply didn't come across as snarky.  I was just trying to point people at the docs, as I am searching for details on a related issue (and still not finding it :) )

Comment: It's fine. It's just funny from my perspective that a piece of documentation written to warn about this surprising behavior ends up legitimizing it.